# Nodejs not updating data to mongodb in for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I wanted to update a collection in mongodb from node js. There have multiple rows need to update so I have done a for loop for this, first of all I did an query then for each result I made another query then I am pushing to an variable then I just wanted to loop through this variable and update data to mongo db here is code

```
let results = await model.find({status: 'active'});
let finalResult = [];

results.forEach( async result=> {
     query = {
     createdAt: {
      $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
      $lte: toDate.getTime(),
    }

     results1 = await model1.find(query);
     results1.forEach(result1=> {
      finalResult.push(result1);
     })
     finalResult.forEach(async result => {
        await model1.updateOne(
            {cId: result.cId},
            {
              $set: {
                updatedct: true
              }
            }
        )
    });
  };
});
```

this updating only one document not for all. can you tell what is my wrong?

Comment: What do you want to update in the document? you can use aggregation pipeline to achieve it.

Comment: I am not updating documents, I wanted to update rows at mongodb

Comment: results1 is already an array, you can just do a loop for objects inside it, and call the updateOne method

Comment: @RonaldDas can you please write an answer for this?

Comment: Mongodb doesn't have rows, it hs collection and documents. It is a document based NoSQL Db.

Comment: May be you can try `bulkWrite` instead of calling updateOne in loop. Just prepare the data to be updated in loop and then outside the loop call `bulkWrite`. Reference can be taken from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya but outside of loop I can get the data finalResult var. this giving me empty array[] at outside of loop

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, something like this should work

```
let results = await model.find({status: 'active'});
let finalResult = [];

results.forEach( async result=> {
     query = {
     createdAt: {
      $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
      $lte: toDate.getTime(),
    }

     results1 = await model1.find(query);
     
     for (const result of results1) {
         //console.log(result.cId) //Check if this has correct value
        await model1.updateOne(
            {cId: result.cId},
            {
              $set: {
                updatedct: true
              }
            }
        )
    });
  };
});
```

Or you could directly update also (Since you querying and than manually updating each document), eg. code

```
let results = await model.find({status: 'active'});
let finalResult = [];

results.forEach( async result=> {
     query = {
     createdAt: {
      $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
      $lte: toDate.getTime(),
    }
    // Directly updating
    await model1.updateMany({...query},{$set: {
                updatedct: true
              }})
     
  };
});
```

Comment: I have tried for first one but not working, only updating one document not all